# How to connect to Oracle server without specifying database name

Tags: c#, database, oracle, tns

My application has a feature to connect to 4 different database servers (MS SQL, MySql, SQLite and Oracle), and if no database exists, it will create a new one with the specified database name. This logic works on all servers, except on Oracle. If the database exists, i can connect to it on all four servers, so i think the problem is not related to my tns, or wrong dll, or anything like that, but maybe my connectionstring is wrong in this case.

The Oracle server version is 11.0.0.1, and i installed the necessary odac drivers. There is a tns set on my pc and everything is working properly when the database exists. In this case the connectionstring looks like this:

```
User Id=<myuser>; Password=<mypassword>; POOLING=true; Connection Lifetime=15;
Connection Timeout=15; incr pool size=10; Data Source=
(
DESCRIPTION=
(ADDRESS=
 (PROTOCOL=TCP)
 (HOST=<myserveraddress>)
 (PORT=<myport>)
)
(
 CONNECT_DATA=
 (SID=<mysid>)
 (SERVICE_NAME=<mydatabasename>)
)
);
```

Now, if i remove the servicename section from the connectionstring, i get an "ORA-12505: TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor" exception.

What should i do when i only want to connect to a server, but not directly to a database?

Comment: you want to check if the `service name` given is up and running ?

Comment: What exactly do you want to connect to if not a database?

Comment: I want to leave the servicename out from the connectionstring, like i do it when connecting to a MSSQL server. So, i want to connect to the server, but not to the database. Imagine a brand new server without any database. What would you specify in the servicename variable? :)

Comment: I think there is a terminology issue here. Without a database instance there is nothing to connect to in Oracle.

Comment: When you install an Oracle server, you dont have a database. My program wants to connect to the server and then create a new database. When the new database is created, i can connect to it with the connectionstring above. I can do it in the other 3 databases, but not with Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

the concept for oracle database creation is different than other databases.

Please click the following link

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/index.htm

and select option "2 Day DBA"

the best way to create a database is to use the graphical interface provided by oracle i.e. start with dbca.bat

Answer (score 0):

You are misunderstanding what is going on here.

In Oracle you don't create a database in your case, but a user / tablespace.

Oracle:

Server > instance (database) > tablespace

Other:

Server > instance > database